# How can I start an instance from the new EC2 CLI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I have an ec2 micro instance. I can start it from the console, ssh into it (using a .pem file) and visit the website it hosts.

Using the old ec2 CLI, I can start the instance and perform other actions including ssh and website access.

I am having trouble with the new ec2 CLI. When I do "aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-xxx" I get the message "A client error (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) occurred when calling the StartInstances operation: The instance ID 'i-xxx' does not exist".

Clearly the instance exists, so I don't what the message is really indicating.

Here is some of my thinking:

1. One difference between the old and new CLI is that the the later used .pem files whereas the new interface uses access key pairs.  The instance has an access key pair associated with is, but have tried all the credentials I can find, and none of them change anything).
2. I tried created an IAM user and a new access key pair for it.  The behavior in all cases is unchanged (start from console or old CLI, web access, ssh) but not using the new CLI.
3. I realize that there is a means for updating the access key pairs by detaching the volume (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966250/change-keypairs-ec2-running-instance)), but the process looks a little scary to me.
4. I realize that I can clone another instance from the image, but the image is a little out of date, and I don't want to lose my changes.

Can anyone suggest what the message really means and what I can do to get around the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct instance ID - that error suggests you do not. What response do you get if you run

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was incomplete - Are you sure you have the correct instance ID - that error suggests you do not. What response do you get if you run

`aws ec2 describe-instances`

That should show your instances, including the one you want to start, and you need to copy the full value from the "InstanceId" field. Also, in the output from describe-instances you should see a stopped state for an instance you're trying to start

`"State": {
    "Code": 80,
    "Name": "stopped"
}`

Comment: I should also add - the .pem file is used to make an SSH connection to the instance once it is already running, the CLI is used to interact with AWS to describe, start, stop, create, delete instances, and so on, so the .pem file is not used by the CLI. You do have to have an access key in order to be able to use the CLI, but the error you are seeing does not indicate that is your problem, if there was an account problem it would not say that the instance ID was not found.

Comment: Is the CLI picking up the correct AWS credentials?  If, for some reason, you have two or more associated with different accounts, and it's using the wrong one, it would say no such instance exists because, in that account, that instance really does not exist.

Comment: The instance-id is correct. It is the same one that is used to start the instance from the console and from the old CLI.

Comment: aws ec2 describe-instances returns no results.

Comment: I understand that .pem files are normally used for ssh. However, using the old CLI, I set two shell variables: 

export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=$EC2_HOME/pk-xxx.pem 
export EC2_CERT=$EC2_HOME/cert-xxx.pem

My assumption was that somehow the old CLI was making using of these files to authenticate.

Comment: I doubt that the CLI is picking up the correct AWS credentials, but I don't know how to check this.  I do have a separate S3 account, that works fine, both from the console and the new CLI. When I use these credentials on the EC2 account, however, they fail in the same way that the other credentials fail.

Is anyone aware of a CLI call that checks credentials?

Comment: The old CLI you're referring to is VERY old and is in fact deprecated so you definitely want to stop using it. The certificates it used are not how you connect with the CLI any more.
You need to now use an access key and secret access key, which you can get for your account in the console - see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html#cli-signup. Then run `aws configure` to set them for the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with credentials.  I had the correct environment
variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY) set. But they didn't match what was in my .aws/credentials file.  That is, despite what it says [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence), the new CLI worked only when I had the environment variables and
the credentials file correct and in sync.

Answer (score -1):

Configure your aws cli with ***"aws configure"*** in new cli instance with region in which your ec2 instance reside. and then try to give the same command. The instance should start.